# xpath query to extract url from a href

Tags: html, xpath, spreadsheet

www.linkedin.com/in/jennifer-smith-aa97685 is in F1
I want extract current company company url using google chrome inspect tool.
I tried a lot but did not work. Here is my code:

```
=importxml(F1, "//*[@id='experience']/ul/li[1]/header/h5[1]/a")

<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/suntrust-bank?trk=ppro_cprof"><img class="lazy-loaded" alt="SunTrust" src="https://media.licdn.com/media/p/5/005/097/1e1/364727b.png"></a>
```

I want to import https://www.linkedin.com/company/suntrust-bank?trk=ppro_cprof in cell G1.

any ideas/help.

Comment: This does not look like the Chrome Inspector to me, do you mean Google Sheets?

Comment: yes, its in google spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

This works for all people profiles:

```
=IMPORTXML("profile url","//*[@data-section='currentPositions']/*[1]/a/@href")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below xpath

```
//table[@class='extra-info']//a[contains(.,'SunTrust Bank')]/@href
```

Comment: it did work with this linkedin profile but i have multiple linkedin profile urls.

Comment: oh that means you need that locator generic so yoy can dentify to any profile in linkden .. right?

Comment: I think google spreadsheet functions are not working. It showing me could not fetch url.  I been extracting linkedin profile info using Importxml. Here are some examples: =ImportXML(F1, "//h1[@id='name']")
=CONCATENATE(IMPORTXML(F1,"//h4[@class='item-title']"))
Could you let me know is there any work around solution(s).